# Ruby Watir-Webdriver's browser wrapper

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to write a wrapper around Watir-Webdriver's Browser object. Mainly, when a user calls

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.link(:text => 'continue').click
```

I want to inspect what the user typed after browser and log it, then call Watir-Webdriver's browser and perform the action.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have a base class that exposes functionality for UI tests. It instantiates the Browser for the user and exposes it as $browser. When derived classes do anything on the $browser object, I want to wrap it around begin/rescue and I want to log what the user is doing. Thus, instead of exposing Watir's Browser object, I want to expose my own object that does the logging prior to calling Watir's Browser object.

Right now, I am achieving this by having a method in my base class that takes a block:

```
def perform(action, delay = 1)
    begin
        yield action if block_given?
        sleep delay
        assert(true)
    rescue  Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, 
            Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException,
            Watir::Exception::ObjectReadOnlyException,
            Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException,
            Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException,
            Watir::Exception::UnknownCellException,
            Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException,
            Watir::Exception::NoStatusBarException,
            Watir::Exception::NavigationException,
            Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException,
            Watir::Exception::UnknownRowException,
            Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError => e
        $log.error(e.message)
        assert(false)
    end
end
```

However, I want to remove this perform method so the caller doesn't have to have any knowledge about perform. I also want to inspect what the caller is doing on the $browser object and log that. I cannot do this here since I can't convert a block to string. :-/

Comment: What are you trying to do? I did not understand the question.

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully, this makes more sense.

Comment: Where I'm getting confused with your question is the exact meaning of "typed after browser". And is the user an actual human? Where is this being typed? And what?

Comment: Similar confusion here as to exactly what benefit you are trying to get from doing things this way.